passing anchor `#[instruction]` argument with another argument results in different address generated
I have my accounts struct like this
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(force_seed: [u8; 32])]
pub struct Dummy<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [RANDOMNESS_ACCOUNT_SEED.as_ref(), &force_seed],
        bump,
        seeds::program = orao_solana_vrf::ID
    )]
    pub random: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

I want to pas in the force_seed argument with another argument, dummy. Dummy will not be used in the Accounts struct, only force_seed. The issue is that when I include dummy, the generated PDA address account here random changes.
 pub fn guess(ctx: Context<Dummy>, dummy: u8,  force_seed: [u8; 32]) -> Result<()> {

        Ok(())
    }


The instructions are passed in order from left to right. So either you change the order of your parameters in the guess instruction or you write your instruction macro like this: #[instruction(dummy: u8, force_seed: [u8; 32])]
